# How to access Pandas pivot-table data

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pivot table:

```
d = c.pivot_table(index=[ 'Material'], columns = ['MvT'], values=['Quantity'], aggfunc=[np.sum],fill_value=0, margins = True)

sum
Quantity
  MvT       601  631  641   All
  Material              
 Type_A      9    2    5    16
 Type_B      6    4    10   20
 Type_C      3    0    2     5
 Type_D      3    2    1     6
 Type_E      1    0    1     2

  All       22    8   19    49
```

I want to display by matplotlib BAR 'All'.
How can I access to 'All'?

```
d.loc[:,'All']
```

doesn't work

```
KeyError: 'All'
```

Comment: `d.loc[:,'All']`?

Comment: question edited: d.loc[:,'All'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `[np.sum]` to `np.sum` , you create a multiple index

```
d = c.pivot_table(index='Material', columns = 'MvT', values='Quantity', aggfunc=np.sum,fill_value=0, margins = True)
```

then

```
d.loc[:,'All']
```